# Css transition is not working in reverse direction

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

**Requirement**: I need smooth animation based on element's height (which is driven by child element)

**Note**: Please click on the element to expand

**JSFiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmq0oqz/4/

**What I have tried:** The element structure will be as follows

```js
document.querySelector('.parent').addEventListener('click', function(eve) {
  eve.currentTarget.className.indexOf('expand') == -1 ? eve.currentTarget.className = 'parent expand' : eve.currentTarget.className = 'parent';
});
```

```css
.parent {
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child-wrap {
    width: 100%;
}
.child1 {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
  transition: height 1s;
}

.child2 {
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  transition: height 1s;
  
}
.parent.expand {
  max-height: 400px;
}
.expand .child-wrap{
  display:table
}
.expand .child2 {
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell;
  
}
.expand .child1 {
  width: 70%;
  display: table-cell;
  
}
p {
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child-wrap">
    <div class="child1">
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
    </div>
    <div class="child2">
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
      <p>hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh hghjghjgjhhjh</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Rules**:
On parent element expand only I need to show one of the child.
Parent element should have certain maximum-height in both the states (collapse/expand)

**Problem I am facing**: transition is working in one direction(collapse to expand) but not in other (expand to collapse).

Comment: Know it's got nothing to do with the question but eve.currentTarget.classList.toggle('expand'); toggle is much better than an if statement :-)

Comment: @AndrewBone Thanks for the info.. I don't know this one :)

Comment: got the same problem as yours, not sure why

Answer (score 3):

You will also need to add the transition to the child2 element as this is the element which is transitioning

```
.child2{
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: red;
  transition:height 1s;
  }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2wgw22g5/10/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have tried the solution u provided.. but it's not working at the actual place.. so recreated the scenario with minute details. Please try this one https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmq0oqz/4/

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,
I have just added a transition effect to your css child elements.

```
.parent{
  max-height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: green;
  transition: max-height 1s ease;
  display: flex;
  overflow:auto;
}
.parent.expand{
  max-height: 400px;
}
.child1{
  width: 70%;
  height: 100px;
-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
   transition: all 2s;
}
.child2{
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  background-color: red;
-webkit-transition: all 2s; /* Safari */
   transition: all 2s;
}
.expand .child2{
  height: 800px;
  width: 30%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I have tried the solution u provided.. but it's not working at the actual place.. so recreated the scenario with minute details. Please try this one https://jsfiddle.net/Lhmq0oqz/4/